# jquery toggle(event,event) hide show question

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

Calling `toggle` takes a long time to load, so I'm trying to add a loading img while loading but it doesn't seem to load when you `.showall` is activated look at `*` in the following code

```
$('#loading').hide();

$(".showall").toggle(
 function(){ 
   $('#loading').show(1); // * added
   $(".toggle_container").slideDown();
   $('#loading').hide(); // * added
  },
 function () { 
   $('#loading').show(1); // * added
   $(".toggle_container").slideUp();
   $('#loading').hide(); // * added
 }  
);
```

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle to it? Also, after you show #loading you immediately hide it, so you don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The other response of calling hide in the callback is the correct approach, but I figured I'd answer to point out why.

There are actually multiple issues here.  Your intention is to show `#loading` then `slideup` and once that is complete, hide `#loading`.  However, when `slideup` is called, the animation is queued up and your code moves on, the code does not wait for `slideup` to complete and then move on to the next line.  This is why you need to use the callback, to call `hide` after `slideup` completes.

Another thing that many people overlook is that `show` and `hide` when called with a duration are animations and are therefore queue, however, **when no duration is passed these calls are NOT animations and will NOT be queued**.  So, calling `show` with a duration and then immediately calling `hide` with no duration will never show the element.  See this for an illustration of that:  http://jsfiddle.net/zZHhm/  notice that you never see DIV2.

Also, the durations passed to `show` and `hide` are in milliseconds, so `hide(1)` gives a duration of 1 millisecond (you may be aware of this).

Answer (score 0):

I admit, something weird is happening while using show/hide with or without parameter. This version works, but I don't know why these methods without parameters doesn't behave as they should.

Code: ( http://jsfiddle.net/z3HRQ/2/ )

```
$('#loading').hide(1);

$('.showall').toggle(
    function () {
        $('#loading').show(1);
        $('.toggle_container').slideUp(function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
        });
    },
    function () {
        $('#loading').show(1);
        $('.toggle_container').slideDown(function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks guys, 

when <div class="toggle_container"> *is busy </div>  is does the same thing which is what I'm having problems with ..